# customvalidator unexpectedly firing with blank text

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I have a class that inherits from CustomValidator which is set to validate a textbox.  The problem is, it is firing even when the textbox is empty.  The ValidateEmptyText property is not set.  Has anyone seen this behaviour with Custom Validation controls and found a cause?

It only does it with server controls which inherit CustomValidator. Using the asp:customvalidator control works fine.  I am using .Net 4.0

Comment: If I set ValidateEmptyText="false" then it still validates the control.  The control value is definitely empty.

Comment: It only does it with server controls which inherit CustomValidator.  Using the asp:customvalidator control works fine.

Comment: @Craig: please edit your question if you have additional info, instead of commenting on it.

Comment: Did you have the "controltovalidate" property set? It's not required for a customvalidator and if empty it can't check that is really shouldn't fire.